# Linux Repositories - Any Limits?

Tags: linux, repository

All or most Linux repositories are voluntarily hosted/mirrored for others to download free software.

For example, you could download the same package(s) over and over again (with the same IP) and make the network slow(er) for others. (e.g. mass installation of multiple computers - which is technically redundant, if you download and deploy once)

But are there any (download) limits or throttling mechanism going on if the repositories are "misused/abused/attacked" like that?
Is it possible to get an IP-Ban?

How or is this even protected at all?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Linux repository"?

Comment: With literally hundreds or thousands of repositories in existence you would be hard put to define a "standard" configuration against network attacks.

Comment: @Kusalananda I mean Software Repositories for distribution e.g. used by package managers

Comment: Debian alone has 342 official mirrors. And those are only the official mirrors, there are thousands of unofficial ones. Many of those mirrors are actually just load balancers behind which are hidden tens or even hundreds of servers. deb.debian.org is backed by a Content Delivery Network, which means that just behind this one URI alone are tens of thousands of servers. And Debian is just one of thousands of Linux distributions. There is no way to list out every single policy of every single server of every single mirror of every single distribution.

Comment: Repositories are usually served by an HTTP server such as apache or nginx. This question could be rephrased as "Are there any limits or throttling mechanism going on for web servers?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are far too many different repositories with different configurations to give an answer valid for everything.

However,

> But are there any (download) limits or throttling mechanism going on if the repositories are "misused/abused/attacked" like that? Is it possible to get an IP-Ban?

Some repositories do enforce limits, and it is possible to get an IP ban on them.

Basically, if you use repositories in a responsible fashion, you shouldn’t run into problems. If you start trying to overload them, you can expect to run into problems at some point or other, including IP bans which may have a bigger impact than you expect (they might affect more than the specific repository which triggered them).